# Problem using authorization_code on deployed IdentityServer4 for a PowerBI Extension. What am I missing?

Tags: powerbi, identityserver4

This one has been driving me mad for a couple of days and I can't find a solution. Can someone point me towards one? Thank you in advance!

What I want:
I want to successfully use the authorization_code flow for a Power BI Extension.

What I've done:
I've setup an OAuth2 flow in Power Query M and when I target my localhost IdentityServer, I can login with the user login screen and I get an Access Token that Power BI can use. This works, but it doesn't work on a published IdentityServer (same code, same database). So what am I missing?

Here's what happens:

I have this Power Query M code (it's pretty standard, I found it online and it works on localhost):

```
StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) =>
let
    authorizeUrl = oauthUrl & "connect/authorize?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([
        response_type = "code",
        client_id = client_id,
        redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
        state = state,
        scope="myscope"
    ])
in
    [
        LoginUri = authorizeUrl,
        CallbackUri = redirect_uri,
        WindowHeight = windowHeight,
        WindowWidth = windowWidth,
        Context = null
    ];

FinishLogin = (context, callbackUri, state) =>
let
    // parse the full callbackUri, and extract the Query string
    parts = Uri.Parts(callbackUri)[Query],
    // if the query string contains an "error" field, raise an error
    // otherwise call TokenMethod to exchange our code for an access_token
    result = if (Record.HasFields(parts, {"error", "error_description"})) then
        error Error.Record(parts[error], parts[error_description], parts)
    else
        TokenMethod("authorization_code", "code", parts[code])
in
    result;

TokenMethod = (grantType, tokenField, code) =>
let
    queryString = [
        grant_type = grantType,
        redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
        client_id = client_id,
        client_secret = client_secret
    ],
    
    queryWithCode = Record.AddField(queryString, tokenField, code),

    tokenResponse = Web.Contents(oauthUrl & "connect/token", [
        Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(queryWithCode)),
        Headers = [
            #"Content-type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            #"Accept" = "application/json"], 
        ManualStatusHandling = {400}
    ]),

    body = Json.Document(tokenResponse),

    result = if (Record.HasFields(body , {"error", "error_description"})) then
        error Error.Record(body[error], body[error_description], body)
    else
        body
in
    result;
```

What happens is that an IE frame pops up to prompt for my credentials:

[The normal login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2aof.png)

Once I login on localhost, I get my AccessToken, life's good :-)

However, once I login on the deployed IdentityServer, I get this one, a 400:

[Failing on deployed IdentityServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpmj.png)

The address is: res://ieframe.dll/http_400_webOC.htm#https://identityserverurl/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3DPowerBI%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Foauth.powerbi.com%252Fviews%252Foauthredirect.html%26state%3D852bddfc-638c-44f6-90be-a04346908753%26scope%3Dmyscope

I think the problem has something to do with Internet Explorer and the way the window is being presented, but I can't figure out why it DOES work on localhost, just NOT on a deployed server. The client settings are identical on both localhost and on the deployed IdentityServer (it's on a develop server; they target the same database).

I know on a deployed IdentityServer the home page is not available, so the "https://identityserverurl/" will give a 404. Is something similar going on here?

What am I missing?

Any help is much appreciated! It's the final step to getting it all to work.

Best regards,
Remco

Update: Added IdentityServer logging and Fiddler Trace:

[image: IdentityServer logging (strikethrough is just name of custom scope and some extra logging for ParameterizedScopeParser)]

[image: Fiddler Trace]

GET /connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=PowerBI&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.powerbi.com%2Fviews%2Foauthredirect.html&state=d2f420fb-a98a-4327-b8f1-ebb8937f8b00&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20myscope HTTP/1.1

GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3DPowerBI%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Foauth.powerbi.com%252Fviews%252Foauthredirect.html%26state%3Dd2f420fb-a98a-4327-b8f1-ebb8937f8b00%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520offline_access%2520myscope HTTP/1.1

There's not much else going on. It just simply stops when I click login.

Comment: Why don't you post a trace of the requests here using Fidler? And what does the log from IdentityServer say?

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks for taking time to help me. I've added some screenshots. There's just not much else going on when I click login. And I'm not used to working with Fiddler. Seems I should invest some time in getting to know how it works.